# Three wires on a light

Tags: electrical

I am trying to install a light that has three wires black white and green. The light I was replacing only had two black and white.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the light fixture box please?

Comment: The green is an option for safety, is screwed to the metal box or connected to bare/green wire, or capped off.  The important info is how the old light was connected, so the new black and white is connected right.

Answer (score 2):

The green wire is a ground wire. That is standard now but many years ago it was not required.

There are several possible installation types, and the exact solution depends on what you have:

- Metal box, bare or green wire attached to the metal box: Attach the green wire to the metal box with a [ground screw](https://amzn.to/3EG6vBs)
- Metal box, no ground wire visible, attached to metal conduit: Attach the green wire to the metal box with a [ground screw](https://amzn.to/3EG6vBs)
- Plastic box, bare or green wire in the box: Attach the green wire to the bare or green wire with a wire nut

If none of those scenarios matches your situation, upload a picture and we'll try to figure something out.

Answer (score 1):

The green wire is safety ground. If there's a green wire in the electrical box, it connects to that. If there isn't a green coming into the box, and the box is metal, there may be a screw in the box you could attach it to.

If you can't manage either of those, I'd just tape the end of that green wire, or put a wire nut on it, to ensure the exposed copper doesn't come into contact with hot. Table lamps don't usually have a safety ground, after all.

And in fact if the box is metal and was grounded, not having a green wire may not matter. Many fixtures are designed to ground themselves to the box via their mounting screws, and that's how many older houses were wired.